# Check mysql domain that is using resources

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have a webserver hosting about 300 websites and sometimes my CPU usage gets close to 100% and when I use "top" in my CENTOS to check who is using all CPU, I discover it's mysql. I would like then to know what website is causing that high mysql CPU usage. With Apache I can know exactly which virtual domain is consuming my cpu, ram, bandwidth... but I have no idea how to do that with mysql. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could check your slow query log. If it's CPU intensive, it may be some heavy hitting queries that take a while to process. Check to make sure your slow query threshold is set to a reasonable amount of time and then look at your log.

When your server is in the middle of a CPU spike, log in and do `show full processlist` to look at the queries that are running at that moment. Is there a higher number of queries than normal? Is there a high number of slow queries than normal?

You could use `show open tables` which will show you what's in the table cache, but it doesn't necessarily tell you what is using up all the resources, but rather which databases/tables are the most active.

Comment: how do I check the slow query log?

Comment: Check the following three variables: `slow_query_log`, `slow_query_log_file`, and `long_query_time`. Look those up in the MySQL documentation and it'll tell you everything you need.